# Getting a "No file was uploaded." response when trying to upload a file using Azure Function's

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to create an Azure Function which uploads to an Azure Storage Blob. I am using Postman to send the request. In Postman, I set the body to `form-data` and the key to `file`, and then attached a test image to see if it will get uploaded. But in my response, I am getting a "No file was uploaded." response.

[image: postman response]

I do not know what is causing this to happen, and I even added additional logging, so I can look at Azure Log stream, and this is the output from Azure Log Stream:

```
2024-01-22T17:21:14Z   [Information]   Request body: ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }
2024-01-22T17:21:14Z   [Information]   Request file: undefined
2024-01-22T17:21:14Z   [Information]   File uploaded: No file was uploaded
```

If you wish to look at the my Azure function app code, the code for the function is here:

```js
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

// Azure Storage connection string
const AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = process.env['AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING'];

app.http('postToICTDatabaseFiles', {
  methods: ['POST'],
  authLevel: 'anonymous',
  handler: async (request, context) => {
    try {
        // Log the request body for debugging
        context.log("Request body:", request.body);

      // Wrap the upload in a new Promise and await it
      const file = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        upload.single('file')(request, {}, function (err) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(request.file);
          }
        });
      });

      // Log the file object for debugging
      context.log("Request file:", file);

      // Print to context.log the file name or if no file was uploaded
      context.log(`File uploaded: ${file ? file.originalname : 'No file was uploaded.'}`);

      // If file is undefined, return an error
      if (!file) {
        return {
          status: 400,
          body: 'No file was uploaded.'
        };
      }

      // Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
      const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);

      // Get a reference to a container
      const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient('files'); // Azure blob storage name

      // Create a new block blob and upload the file
      const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(file.originalname);
      const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(file.buffer, file.buffer.length);

      context.log(`Upload block blob ${file.originalname} successfully`, uploadBlobResponse.requestId);

      // Respond with the result
      return {
        status: 200,
        body: `File uploaded successfully. Blob URL: ${blockBlobClient.url}`
      };
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle errors

      // Log or console the error details for debugging
      context.log(error.message);
      return {
        status: 500,
        body: error.message
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created Http trigger function with runtime stack javascript.

I have tried with the below code to upload the blob into azure storage container.

**Function code:**

```
const { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const multipart = require('parse-multipart');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    if (req.method === 'POST' && req.headers['content-type'] && req.headers['content-type'].startsWith('multipart/form-data')) {
        // Encode body to base64 string
        const bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body);
        // Get boundary for multipart data
        const boundary = multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']);
        // Parse the body
        const parts = multipart.Parse(bodyBuffer, boundary);

        if (parts.length > 0) {
            const storageAccountName = 'pavanstoragehello';
            const storageAccountKey = 'your-storage account access key';
            const containerName = 'pavan';

            const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(storageAccountName, storageAccountKey);
            const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net`, sharedKeyCredential);
            const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

            const blobName = parts[0].filename;
            const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

            const uploadOptions = { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: parts[0].type } };

            // Upload the file to Azure Storage
            await blockBlobClient.upload(parts[0].data, parts[0].data.length, uploadOptions);

            context.res = {
                body: { message: 'File uploaded successfully.' },
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                status: 200
            };
        } else {
            context.res = {
                body: { message: 'No file data found in the request.' },
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                status: 400
            };
        }
    } else {
        context.res = {
            body: { message: 'Invalid request. Please use a POST request with "multipart/form-data" content type.' },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            status: 400
        };
    }

    context.done();
};
```

**function.json:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

By using the POST `Endpoint` I can able to send the file through form-data to azure blob storage.

[image]

I am able to see the uploaded file in azure blob storage container. check below:

**Output:**

[image]